Merge two dependent artifacts
I have a build that creates a release bundle. It depends on two other builds and their artifacts. Build 1 produces regular artifact with a directory called docs/a. Build 2 produces zipped artifact - result-123.zip - that also contains docs folder, with some sub-directories - docs/b and docs/c.
Is there a way to combine the two artifacts into final with one uniform docs folder? What is the proper format?
\docs\
    a\
    b\
    c\

But all I get is either just \docs\a or
\docs\
    a\
    result-123.zip

TeamCity Enterprise 2023.11.3 (build 147512)
